# Where clause in count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, where-clause

Is there any way to specify a where clause for count in t-sql?

What I'd like to do (mind that this is whishful coding) is:

```
SELECT COUNT([column] WHERE [column]>20) AS [a], 
       COUNT([column] WHERE [column]<20 AND [column]>10) AS [b] 
FROM [table];
```

instead of having two queries

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table] WHERE [column]>20;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table] WHERE [column]<20 AND [column]>10;
```

Comment: Just use a case and a sum.  This has got to be a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a SUM() inside a case statement in SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628585/how-to-do-a-sum-inside-a-case-statement-in-sql-server)

Comment: @blam: I didn't think about it, and I didn't know it could be written inside count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple case statement:

```
select
count (case when [column]>20 then 1 else null end) as [a],
count (case when [column]<20 and [column]>10 then 1 else null end) as [b]
from
table
```