# How to sum and count in attendance using pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `Mark_Attendance` and it contains:

```
Class | [Status] | [DateTime]  | S_Adm_No  | Gender 
------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------
NUR   | P        | 2017-04-19  | 1101      | Male
NUR   | A        | 2017-04-19  | 1102      | Male
NUR   | P        | 2017-04-19  | 1103      | Female
NUR   | A        | 2017-04-19  | 1104      | Female
KG    | P        | 2017-04-19  | 1105      | Male
KG    | A        | 2017-04-19  | 1106      | Male
KG    | P        | 2017-04-19  | 1107      | Female
KG    | A        | 2017-04-19  | 1108      | Female
```

Now I want to show my result like

```
Class|ttl|total_male|ttl_FeMale|Ttl_Pr|Pr_Male|Pr_Female|Ttl_Ab|Ab_Female|Ab_Mal2
NUR  |4  |  2       |   2      | 2    |2      | 2       |2     |2        |2
KG   |4  |  2       |   2      | 2    |2      | 2       |2     |2        |2
```

For getting this result what query should I use in SQL Server.

Comment: What time do you need to hand in your homework assignment? On a side-note: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly your output is wrong

Proper query and output should be :

```
select Class, Count(Class) as ttl,
Sum(Case when Gender = 'Male' Then 1 Else 0 End) as Total_Male,
Sum(Case when Gender = 'Female' Then 1 Else 0 End) as Total_Female,
Sum(Case when Status = 'P' Then 1 Else 0 End) as Total_Present,
Sum(Case when Status = 'P' and Gender = 'Male' Then 1 Else 0 End) as Total_Male_Present,
Sum(Case when Status = 'P' and Gender = 'Female' Then 1 Else 0 End) as Total_Female_Present,
Sum(Case when Status = 'A' Then 1 Else 0 End) as Total_Absent,
Sum(Case when Status = 'A' and Gender = 'Male' Then 1 Else 0 End) as Total_Male_Absent,
Sum(Case when Status = 'A' and Gender = 'Female' Then 1 Else 0 End) as Total_Female_Absent
from  Mark_Attendance
group by Class;
```

and output should be :

```
Class  ttl         Total_Male  Total_Female Total_Present Total_Male_Present Total_Female_Present Total_Absent Total_Male_Absent Total_Female_Absent
------ ----------- ----------- ------------ ------------- ------------------ -------------------- ------------ ----------------- -------------------
KG     4           2           2            2             1                  1                    2            1                 1
NUR    4           2           2            2             1                  1                    2            1                 1
```

If you want to understand how did I achieve this result read about

- [Group by clause](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm)
- [Sum over case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628585/how-to-do-a-sum-inside-a-case-statement-in-sql-server)

I strongly discourage people who post questions without showing their efforts.

Comment: If you discourage people who post without showing effort then why give them the answer???

Comment: Because irrespective of anything, SO is meant to help people. We can guide them by providing reading material to learn along with answers

Comment: I guess we will have to disagree. I don't believe anyone is helped if they have their homework done for them, they will never learn. SO has defined rules so it's definitely not "irrespective of anything". https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: And has SO defined which questions should come under homework ? The point is, we all started from somewhere. If we discourage them so much, they might never generate interest in that field. You can flag this answer. If under review it is found not worthy, I will delete it. Thanks

Comment: The point is the user made no effort at all to solve their problem, simply took a question from a test and posted on SO for someone else to solve. They won't learn anything, they will pass their test and they will have no SQL skills when they get a job. So really we're making the coding world worse by doing someone's homework for them. :)

Comment: @JacobH Good points but a bit dramatic.  Anyone who hires an entry-level SQL coded based purely on a degree or certificate without any kind of technical screening deserves what they get.  But, both of you bring up good points.  I refrained from answering because he didn't post any effort - even after being asked for it.

Comment: @StanShaw time ran out on his quiz. :)

Comment: Lol - weird that he asked for this to be pivoted.  That's a bizarre approach to this problem - gotta be homework!